# How can I send HTTP Basic Authentication headers in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, httpclient, http-authentication

I am not sure how to send HTTP Auth headers.

I have the following HttpClient to get requests, but not sure how I can send requests?

```
public class RestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            /*
             * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
             * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the
             * BufferedReader return null which means there's no more data to
             * read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder and returned as
             * String.
             */
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        /*
         * This is a test function which will connects to a given rest service
         * and prints it's response to Android Log with labels "Praeda".
         */
        public JSONObject connect(String url) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Prepare a request object
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // Execute the request
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                // Examine the response status
                Log.i("Praeda", response.getStatusLine().toString());

                // Get hold of the response entity
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    // A Simple JSON Response Read
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    String result = convertStreamToString(instream);

                    // A Simple JSONObject Creation
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                    instream.close();

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return connect(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the HttpClient [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) and in their [sample code](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Comment: Some methods in the documentation don't exist on the android platform.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the documentation of HttpClient can help: [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html)

Comment: FYI, your link is for HttpClient 3.x, and Android has HttpClient 4.x built in.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android compiles HttpClient 4.0.x instead of 3.x, below snippet is for your reference.

```
    if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
        AuthScope authScope = new Au    HttpRequestInterceptor preemptiveAuth = new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context.getAttribute(
                ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
        HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);thScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort());
        Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(authScope);
        if (creds != null) {
            authState.setAuthScheme(new BasicScheme());
            authState.setCredentials(creds);
        }
    }
}    
};
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(preemptiveAuth, 0);
```