# Problem sending HTTP headers in Java

Tags: java, android, json, http, httpclient

Am I correctly sending an HTTPPost? I am checking my encodedAuthString against my webserver and can verify the string is correct. Not sure why I am unable to authenticate.

```
public JSONObject connect(String url) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Prepare a request object
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            String authString = usernameEditText.getText().toString() + ":" + passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            String encodedAuthString = Base64.encodeToString(authString.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
            String finalAuthString = "Basic " + encodedAuthString;

            // Execute the request
            HttpResponse response;
            try {  
                httppost.addHeader("Authorization", finalAuthString);

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                // Examine the response status
                Log.i("Praeda", response.getStatusLine().toString());

                // Get hold of the response entity
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    // A Simple JSON Response Read
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    String result = convertStreamToString(instream);

                    // A Simple JSONObject Creation
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                    instream.close();

                    return json;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return connect(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            String authorized = "200";
            String unauthorized = "401";
            String notfound = "404";
            String status = new String();

            try {
                // Get the messages array
                JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");
                status = response.getString("status");

                if(status.equals(authorized))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authorized",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if (status.equals(unauthorized))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unauthorized",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(status.equals(notfound))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

When I hard-code the encoded string, everything is fine.

When I use the Base64 encoder I get the same results as the encoded string, but the server returns a 401.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting any headers in this code. Use `setHeader()` to set headers. This too is covered in the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e78) for HttpClient, as was the information from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250968/how-can-i-send-http-basic-authentication-headers-in-android/4251003#4251003).

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/15-HttpClient/Patchy/) that sets the Authorization header. Note that it uses a separate Base64 encoder, since the built-in one only showed up with Android 2.2, IIRC.

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Considering that I have dozens of students and more dozens of subscribers every month trying the sample I linked to above, I feel rather confident that it works. You will need an identi.ca account to try it, including having clicked through on the email confirmation they send out.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks. I have updated my code to match your example. I am using addHeader() and setEntity() but still no luck. Your code is almost identical to mine.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Updated. I hard-coded the authorization header and everything works. When I don't hard code, i get the same string, but get a 401 back from the server.

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: If you have not done so already, switch to the Base64 encoder included in my project -- I have not tried the one in Android 2.2. Also, if this is your server, log what you are getting for the authentication string on the server side.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Your Base64 encoder worked. I am not sure why Google's included encoder was not working. Thanks for your persistence and great example.

Comment: Hi, I have same code to use in webservice call but it gives me login error status of http is 200. so what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw extra `\n` in the string, so instead of using default option, I used `no_wrap` option like this:

> Base64.encodeToString(authordata.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

and it worked for me.