# Handling windows security popup while web page loading using Selenium and AutoIt

Tags: selenium, authentication, popup, selenium-rc

I have a web based application with windows security popup displayed as soon the first web page starts loading and the page completes loading only after we provide login credentials.

I have written following script, but it is not going to next code line after `selenium.open("/faces/Main");` and finally fails with default timeout error message.

Result console:

```
Timeout 30000ms
```

Selenium1 code:

```
package first;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;



public class Auth_assign {

private Selenium selenium;

   @BeforeClass
   public void setup() 
   {             
          selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444, "*firefox C:/Program Files/FF 7.1/firefox.exe", "http://qa02.mydomain.com");
          selenium.start();
          selenium.windowMaximize();

   }

   @AfterClass(alwaysRun=true) 
   public void stopSelenium() {  
   //this.selenium.stop(); 
   } 




   @Test (description="Authentication pop-up")     
          public void Auth_popup() throws Exception
          {


          System.out.print("Unity page\n ");
          try
          {
          selenium.open("/faces/Main");
          Thread.sleep(10000);

          System.out.print("Window \n ");


          String[] dialog;

          dialog = new String[] { "Login_Dialog.exe","Authentication Required","test46#", "test123"};
          System.out.print( dialog);
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dialog);


          selenium.select("//select[@id='qryId1::criteriaItems::content']", "Customer Name");
          selenium.type("//input[@id='qryId1:criterionValue::content']", "Search Company");
          selenium.click("//a[@id='qryId1::search_icon']");
          selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");

          selenium.click("//a[@id='t1:0:gl1']");


          } catch (SeleniumException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


   }      

Login.exe code

;~ ------------------------------------------------------------
;~ Login_dialog.au3
;~ To handle the Authentication Dialogbox
;~ Create By: Gaurang Shah
;~ Usage: Login_dialog.au3 "Dialog Title" "User Name" "Password"
;~ ------------------------------------------------------------
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","2")

if $CmdLine[0] < 3 then
msgbox(0,"Error","Supply all the Arguments, Dialog title User Name, Password")
Exit
EndIf

WinWait($CmdLine[1]) ; match the window with substring
$title = WinGetTitle($CmdLine[1]) ; retrives whole window title
ControlSend($title,"","Edit2",$CmdLine[2]);Sets User Name
ControlSend($title,"","Edit3",$CmdLine[3]);Sets Password
ControlClick($title,"","OK");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide credential in base url. For example if your base url is 
http://www.mysite.com/ then you can provide it as 
 http://user:pwd@www.mysite.com/

Comment: Thanks user861594 for your reply.

I tried giving base url as http://test64#:test123:qa02.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the username and password in a Authorization header, this may help: [How can I send HTTP Basic Authentication headers in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250968/how-can-i-send-http-basic-authentication-headers-in-android)

Comment: Thanks user861594 for your reply.

I tried giving base url as http://test64#:test123:qa02.mydomain.com

When i run the script. I got following error. Please check

`FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:107)
 at first.Yahoo_assign.setup(Yahoo_assign.java:19)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 
SKIPPED: Auth_popup
         Authentication pop-up`

Comment: You need to pass the username and password as an Authorization header, not in the url, try looking at this example: http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java_Servlets/code36.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your autoit script before security popup comes. Else you never get your control back. I mean before your main page selenium.open("/faces/Main");

Comment: Thanks thawa for your reply!

When I try to call my script before `selenium.open("faces/Main")` I'm not getting Authentication pop-up and following error is shown at the end

`Timed out after 30000ms` Please suggest.