# apache httpclient doesn't set basic authentication credentials

Tags: java, httpclient, basic-authentication

Have a look at the following code:

```
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            http.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials( 
                                                Configuration.username, 
                                                Configuration.developerKey ) );

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strURL);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity( ac.toXMLString() );
            entity.setContentType("text/xml");
            post.setEntity( entity );
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = http.execute( post );
```

It produces no errors. However a response from the server I get "No Authorization header". Checking the request with Wireshark unveils that there is indeed no basic authentication set.

How is that possible?

Comment: do your other headers get set? for instance is your Content-Type set to text/xml?

Comment: Yes, besides the authentication stuff everything seems to be proper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, by default the basic authentication is turned off. However, enabling it is far too complicated ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014700/preemptive-basic-authentication-with-apache-httpclient-4)) . Therefore one can use this code, which works fine:

```
DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strURL);
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                    Configuration.username, 
                    Configuration.developerKey);
post.addHeader( BasicScheme.authenticate(creds,"US-ASCII",false) );
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity( ac.toXMLString() );
entity.setContentType("text/xml");
post.setEntity( entity );
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = http.execute( post );
```

Comment: can you tell me what `ac` is referring to when you call `ac.toXMLString()`?

Comment: `ac` is an object of a custom class I've written and the `toXMLString()` is a method that I implemented myself (like `toString()`). The results is an xml string for an http API. Since this is the POST's request payload this can be any arbitrary text and is not directly related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

User of credential provider

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(apiUser,apiPassword);
provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(apiHost, apiPort, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), credentials);     
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory commons = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
```